# What does "wrt" mean?

Tags: meaning, abbreviations, acronyms

What is the meaning of *wrt* in the following text?

> I think this is an excellent idea, but I'd like to see this explicitly reframed under the banner of providing Drupal.org data through publicly-accessible APIs. We started kicking off at least one discussion like that **wrt** Git over at http://groups.drupal.org/node/126529, which also led back to "#112805: XML-RPC Interface".

Answer (score 46, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "with respect to".

Edit: regarding the lack of punctuation (thanks for bringing it up, ukayer), that's definitely because of the informal nature of the context. It would be more standard to write it as *w.r.t.*, except that in any context where punctuation matters, you probably shouldn't use this abbreviation in the first place.

Comment: There seem to be a class of abbreviations such as wrt that don't require any punctuation or capitalization, any idea why?

Comment: It's not that they don't require capitalisation or punctuation, but that they're generally used in terser forms of communication like e-mails, short memoranda and SMS messages, where haste rules the day. There are some older abbreviations (such as *c* for *with*) that are derived from handwritten abbreviations that were either underlined and raised above the baseline of the text or overlined -- the abbreviations survived the transition to the typewriter for business use, but the lining and position didn't.

Comment: Using w.r.t. is definitely acceptable in even the most formal technical contexts, e.g. in published mathematical research.  In fact, I remember some discussion of the fact that David Foster Wallace over-enthusiastically embraced this and other technical jargon in a non-fiction book he wrote about the notion of infinity.

Comment: @Martha, Isn't it with "regards" to?

Comment: @Pacerier: I dunno, I wouldn't personally say "with regards to" - "regards" requires a different preposition, generally "in".

Comment: is it okay to bring "to" after "w.r.t."? e.g. "...compute cost function w.r.t. to the parameters of the system..."

Comment: @ShayanAmani, no, that would be like saying "enter your PIN number at the ATM machine" (enter your **p**ersonal **i**dentification **n**umber number at the **a**utomated **t**eller **m**achine machine): "...compute cost function **w**ith **r**espect **t**o to the parameters of the system..."

Answer (score 24):

WRT is an abbreviation that stands for **with respect to** or **with regard to**